# Find average of each array within an array

Tags: javascript, math

I'm trying to write a `map`/`reduce` to get the average of each array within an array.

For example.

```
[[1][2,3][4,5,6,7]] => [1, 2.5, 5.5]
```

Right now this is my code where result is the array of arrays:

```
result.map(array => {
  return array.reduce((a, b) => (a + b)) / array.length;
})
```

```js
const result = [
  [1],
  [2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6, 7]
]

console.log(result.map(array => {
  return array.reduce((a, b) => (a + b)) / array.length;
}))
```

Any help to get the desired output is much appreciated. As it stands, my output is reducing to an array of `NaN`'s instead of the averages.

Comment: With the syntax corrected your code works. The problem is somewhere else. For example the `result` array contains non numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a closing parentesis.

By using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with arrays with unknown length, you need to take a start value, which is in this case of a length of zero the result.

```js
var result = [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]],
    avg = result.map(array => array.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / array.length);
    //                                                    ^^^                ^
    //                                                    optional           required

console.log(avg);
```

Comment: Not really `[1].reduce((a, b) => a + b)` The problem would be for empty arrays.

Answer (score 1):

you must provide a second argument to the reduce function, the initial value of `a`. So:

```
result.map(array => {
  return array.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / array.length;
});
```

You may also want to ensure that `array.length > 0` before you divide by it

Comment: OP's code works fine without the the *initialValue* argument as well